# displaying output of variable length in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to create a RMarkdown file that could output each and every element of a vector in a separate line. For instance, I would like all elements of the vector

```
c <- c("elephants", "dogs", "rhinos", "lions", "turtles")
```

to show in a separate line as:

```
elephants
dogs
rhinos
lions
turtles
```

To be clear, I would like these lines to show in the knitted Word document, not in a code as above (I didn't know how else to write in separate lines above).

Please see the following minimal reproducible example:

````
---
title: "The Report"
author: "Jabba the Hutt"
date: "3/3/2020"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r, include = FALSE}

c <- c <- c("elephants", "dogs", "rhinos", "lions", "turtles")

```

`r c`

writeLines(c)
````

The expression `r c` only displays the elements separated by a comma, I would like each of them in a separate line.

I've tried all kind of weird and wonderful symbols within the elements of the vector so far, including "&nbsp", "\", and "
" without success. I managed to build a text-file from within R and then transform it to Word format with pandoc(), however would like to know if a similar strategy would work from within RMarkdown.

The reason I would like to use a vector as above, is that in my original code the output is of variable length and I cannot think of another way to hold the data.

Comment: You could try `cat(c, sep = "\n")` in a chunk with option `results = 'asis'`.

Comment: Hi Yozef. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a table for that?

Comment: Hi Stephanie, thanks for your input, however your suggestion above works only for the code section, if I chose to show it. I'm rather thinking about showing several paragraphs of text, the number of which would depend on the raw data to be analysed. The reason why I would like to have this output is because of the amount of text in the the raw data and no alternative way to display it conveniently (that I know of).

Comment: Most likely you need double "\n\n" in Stephanes suggestion to get it to output correctly, i.e. `cat(c, sep="\n\n") ` (don't forget to set `results='asis'`)